# SQL to XML, combining two nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Currently I have a large SQL Server script that is outputting to XML. To summarize one of the nodes is duplicating. Below is the relevant snippet. I am looking consolidate some of the nodes into one but can't seem to get the syntax correct. See below for current and desired output examples.

```sql
DECLARE @CRWGroups TABLE (ClientID INT, intRegistrationWizardID INT, nvhProfileItemName VARCHAR(MAX), intProfileItemID INT, bitSelected BIT, intProfileItemOptionItemID INT, bitAnswer BIT
                        ,dteAnswerStart DATE, decWeight DEC(5,2))
INSERT INTO @CRWGroups (ClientID, intRegistrationWizardID, nvhProfileItemName, intProfileItemID, bitSelected, intProfileItemOptionItemID, bitAnswer, dteAnswerStart, decWeight)

SELECT crw.intClientID, crw.intRegistrationWizardID, pi.nvhProfileItemName, crwegipi.intProfileItemID, crwegipi.bitSelected, pioi.intProfileItemOptionItemID, 
    crwegipib.bitAnswer, crwegipid.dteAnswerStart, pioi.decWeight from tblClientRegistrationWizard crw
INNER JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizardElement crwe ON crwe.intClientRegistrationWizardID = crw.intClientRegistrationWizardID
INNER JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizardElementGroup crweg ON crweg.intClientRegistrationWizardElementID = crwe.intClientRegistrationWizardElementID
LEFT JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItem_ProfileItem crwegipi ON crwegipi.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupID = crweg.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupID
LEFT JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItem_ProfileItemOptionItem crwegipioi ON crwegipioi.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID = crwegipi.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID
LEFT JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItem_ProfileItemBool crwegipib ON crwegipib.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID = crwegipi.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID
LEFT JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItem_ProfileItemDate crwegipid ON crwegipid.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID = crwegipi.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID
LEFT join tblProfileItem pi ON pi.intProfileItemID = crwegipi.intProfileItemID
LEFT JOIN tblProfileItemOptionItem pioi ON pioi.intProfileItemOptionItemID = crwegipioi.intProfileItemOptionItemID
LEFT JOIN tblProfileItemBool pib ON pib.intProfileItemID = crwegipib.intClientRegistrationWizardElementGroupItemProfileItemID
WHERE crw.intRegistrationWizardID = 49 AND (crwegipi.bitSelected = 1 OR crwegipib.bitAnswer = 1)

SELECT(
    SELECT
        (SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN cg.intProfileItemID IN (5174,4864) THEN '10'
            WHEN cg.intProfileItemID = 4862 THEN '11' END 
        FROM @CRWGroups cg WHERE cg.intProfileItemID IN (5174,4864,4862) AND cg.ClientID = c.ClientID
        FOR XML PATH ('EmpStat'),type)

        ,(SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN cg.intProfileItemID IN (4864,5174,4862) THEN (SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, cg.dteAnswerStart) = '1900-01-01' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), cg.dteAnswerStart, 120) END, '')) END
        FROM @CRWGroups cg WHERE cg.intProfileItemID IN (4864,5174,4862) AND cg.ClientID = c.ClientID
        FOR XML PATH ('DateEmpStatApp'),type)       

        ,(SELECT CASE WHEN cg.intProfileItemID IN (5180) THEN (SELECT 'LOU' AS 'ESMType', '2' AS 'ESMCode' FOR XML PATH ('EmploymentStatusMonitoring'),type) END)
        ,(SELECT CASE WHEN cg.intProfileItemID IN (4868) THEN (SELECT 'BSI' AS 'ESMType', '1' AS 'ESMCode' FOR XML PATH ('EmploymentStatusMonitoring'),type) END)

    FROM @CRWGroups cg WHERE cg.ClientID = c.ClientID AND cg.intProfileItemID IN (5180,4868) 
    FOR XML PATH ('LearnerEmploymentStatus'),type)
FROM tblClient c 
INNER JOIN tblClientRegistrationWizard crw ON crw.intClientID = c.ClientID WHERE crw.intRegistrationWizardID = 49
```

Currently this snippet will produce the following result:

```
<LearnerEmploymentStatus>
  <EmpStat>11</EmpStat>
  <DateEmpStatApp>2017-06-05</DateEmpStatApp>
  <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
    <ESMType>BSI</ESMType>
    <ESMCode>1</ESMCode>
  </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
</LearnerEmploymentStatus>
<LearnerEmploymentStatus>
  <EmpStat>11</EmpStat>
  <DateEmpStatApp>2017-06-05</DateEmpStatApp>
  <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
    <ESMType>LOU</ESMType>
    <ESMCode>2</ESMCode>
  </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
</LearnerEmploymentStatus>
```

I am hoping to get it exporting in this format:

```
<LearnerEmploymentStatus>
  <EmpStat>11</EmpStat>
  <DateEmpStatApp>2017-06-05</DateEmpStatApp>
  <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
    <ESMType>BSI</ESMType>
    <ESMCode>1</ESMCode>
  </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
  <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
    <ESMType>LOU</ESMType>
    <ESMCode>2</ESMCode>
  </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
</LearnerEmploymentStatus>
```

Note there is only one EmploymentStatus node and contained inside are the two EmploymentStatusMonitoring nodes.

Comment: Curious as I cannot test without data, just before the outer `FOR XML PATH ('LearnerEmploymentStatus'), type)` add in `GROUP BY cg.intProfileItemID`.

Comment: Same result unfortunately